# Uploading image with parameters using multipart/form data in swift

Tags: php, ios, swift, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an image at **specific** path of my server. That path will be determined by parameters sent from `multipart/form-data` request.

**Problem**: The image is not uploaded to the specified path, instead, uploaded to root of my server.

I am calling an API that has a php function to save that image to the specified path. I think that PHP function is not getting the path from parameters correctly.

API that i am calling looks something like

https://storage.myWebsiteName.com/upload_image.php/

Contents of upload_image.php

```
   <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 

//Unable to get path parameter and store in @target_dir, instead this function stores image in root
$target_dir = $_GET["path"];


$name = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir . $name;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

$actual_name = strtolower(
    pathinfo(
            $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"],PATHINFO_FILENAME));


    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo $name;
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }

?>
```

I am getting image from `UIImagePickerController` and passing the image to  this function which makes `multipart/form-data` Request

```
func postImageToDB(image : UIImage) {

    let imagePostUrlStr =  "https://myWebsiteName.com/upload_image.php/"

    guard let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
      return
    }
    //want to save my image to this directory which is inside root
    let params = ["path" : "Brainplow/001243192018125835"]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiPartFormData: MultipartFormData) in
      //append path parameter
      for (key, value) in params {
        multiPartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
      }
      multiPartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "fileToUpload", fileName: "testfilename.png", mimeType: "image/png")

    }, to: imagePostUrlStr) { (result: SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) in
      switch result {
      case .success(request: let uploadRequest, _, _ ):


        uploadRequest.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

          print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")

        })

        uploadRequest.responseString { response in
          print("printing response string")
          print(response.value as Any)
          print(response)
          print(response.result)

        }

      case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }


  }
```

**Note**: Inside php function, if i set the directory to a **constant** string, it does save in that path. like if i do something below

```
$target_dir = "Brainplow"
```

That works fine, but i need to determine this directory from params sent from `multipart/form-data` request

My image directory is as follows

**Root Directory**
[image: Root Directory]

**Child Directory**

[image: Child Directory]

**Grand Child Directory**
[image: Grand Child Directory]

So, i want to be able to pass a path (example : "Brainplow/01113132018112642/") as a parameter to request

PHP function should get the path from parameter and put the image there

According to my research and struggle, issue is with PHP function. So maybe instead of using

```
$target_dir = $_GET["path"];
```

I may have to use

```
$target_dir = $_POST["path"];
```

But i don't know PHP much. But maybe there is another issue. But my swift code is working fine. Just my image is not being place in the path i am providing.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Any reason for down voting the question please ?

Comment: _"I may have to use $target_dir = $_POST["path"];"_ - Have you tried it?

Comment: not tried that though. Gonna try it now

Comment: You should always do everything you can to try and solve your issue yourself _before_ posting a question. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: After all the struggle. that was the issue. I had to change `$target_dir = $_GET["path"];` to `$target_dir = $_POST["path"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the PHP function

changed this line

```
$target_dir = $_GET["path"];
```

To

```
$target_dir = $_POST["path"];
```

And it is working Now

Comment: you can also use $_request['path'] 

more info:: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 0):

**Complete solution to Upload multipart image with parameters**

```
#import Alamofire

func multipartImage(data:Data?, url:String,jsonInput:[String: String], completion: @escaping (_ result: DataResponse<Any>) -> Void) {

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:
            { (multipartFormData) in

                if data != nil {
                    multipartFormData.append(data!, withName:"user_image", fileName:"image.jpg", mimeType:"image/jpeg")
                }else{
                    multipartFormData.append("".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "user_image")
                }


                for (key, value) in jsonInput
                {
                    multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
        }, to:url, method: .post, headers: headers)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _ , _ ):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure:
                    { (progress) in
                        //Print progress
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    completion(response)

                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError.localizedDescription)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant. because Question was about how to save the file to the path set by request parameter. As i mentioned in question if i use hard coded path, my swift code was working fine.